# End of observation window for estimating Weibull distribution

Tags: survival, weibull-distribution

I have a dataset on which I'm trying to estimate Weibull distribution CDF as population's survival function.

My question is about gathering data points on which CDF will be estimated. I'm going to establish death rates of my subjects after 1, 2, ..., 28 days. Right now, when establishing the death rate after, say, 4 days, I exclude all the subjects born later than 4 full days before the end of my available data. If it's 5 days, more subjects are excluded. This means that all death rates are calculated on different samples. One of the problems with that is that death rate after 4 days can be higher than the death rate after 5 days, which is counterintuitive when trying to fit a distribution to the sample.

Should I exclude all subjects younger than 28 days instead? I would lose a fair share of subjects that way, but it's something I can afford as I have a lot of observations and death rates don't seem to change with birth time. But are there legitimate reasons to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that you cannot use data from observations born 4 days ago to measure whether they died after 5 days - that wouldn't make any sense. The concept you explained is called *censoring* (as you perhaps already know).

The situation you describe to me sounds like a standard *discrete* survival model for which a simpler logistic regression could do the job. Or is there any particular reason why you try to fit a Weilbul function?

Comment: I was not aware of the term _censoring_, thanks. I don't think I've made myself clear, though - my dilemma is whether I should use data from observations born 4 days ago to measure whether they died within 4 days (knowing that to fit a distribution I also need to check mortality after 5 days, and I won't be able to use the same sample as in case of 4 days) or just exclude all subjects younger than my maximum length of observation window.

Comment: As for your question - in my study survival could be measured continously, too - it's just my choice of gathering data points, I'm measuring mortality after each full day. It's not necessary for me to estimate continuous mortality - between the observation window lengths for which datapoints exist - but I'm interested in estimating beyond the observation window - a few weeks forward.

I use Weibull because it comes easiest for me. Could you point me to any resource on use of logistic regression in survival analysis?

Comment: If you want to do proper discrete survival analysis (e.g. for university or publication), I would recommend you to read the 150 relevant pages in Singer & Willet (https://www.amazon.co.uk/Applied-Longitudinal-Data-Analysis-Occurrence/dp/0195152964). It reads more like a novel but explains the technique sound but not mathematically - I just read it myself. However, in terms of predicting beyond the time horizon for which you have data, that's rather speculative ... but that's what the forecasting literature on trends & co is all about (but I don't know much about this)

Comment: In terms of your censoring comment/question, I guess it will all make sense once you read a bit more about survival analysis. (If you want to do continuous survival analysis, that's okay ... but it all will make more sense to you if you have done discrete survival analysis beforehand; at least that's my experience)